# Is it possible to specify what the label text of a geochart legend scale?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

In the `options` of a geochart, can I distinctly change the label text that is displayed.
I have data which is a percentage but in my data table is just a number. The colorAxis therefore is:

```
colorAxis: {
values: [0, 70],
colors: ['#FFFFFF','#FF0000']
}
```

(I am limiting my data to 70%)
Now on the chart the scale/legend displays as **"0[colors]70"**

Is there anyway that I can make each number on the end of this scale display the '%' sign after.
Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2xmuwxed/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the [google API reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?hl=ja#Configuration_Options) , so I'd say it's not possible.

You could maybe get into the iframe and modify its contents, but I think you'd run into cross-origin problems. Sorry to disappoint you :-(